# intellij idea 16 add -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 in the idea64.exe.vmoptions and idea.exe.vmoptions

Tags: intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8

I find it didn't work when i add `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` in the `idea64.exe.vmoptions` and `idea.exe.vmoptions`.but when i add it to the setting of the VM option,it work well.
I don't like add it everytime i make a new project. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? See http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/ and edit the encodings of File | Other Settings | Default Settings.

Comment: all the file encoding is utf-8.but the Chinese couldn't display correctly in the console when the tomcat start.My english is broken.so if I have some mistake in expressing ,forgive me,please.

Comment: Maybe you should modify `startup.sh` script of Tomcat to use this option by default.

Comment: thanks,i solve the program by add the `JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"` in the `catalina.bat`(my system is win10).